# Alternative to deeply nested resources in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is an alternative to deeply nesting my resources. I dont want the following design:

```
resources :users do
  resources :dashboards do
    resources :comments, :charts
    end
  end
```

A user has a dashboard and a dashboard will have several charts and comments.

What is the alternative? I have heard its not a good idea to be nesting routes like this deeply. Or atleast no more than 1 level.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the url is there mostly for the user's convenience. If it makes sense to have a nesting, it should be there.

I assume, `:users` is there for authentication and authorization. So it would be logical to not show `/users/2/` at the start of each url, unless people can view each others dashboards.

Comment: people can only see the dashboard if its shared with them